pass arguments with ShellExecute to Powershell with admin
I'm trying to run PowerShell in admin using ShellExecute within a Qt program, but the arguments don't seem to be transferring.
QString ruleName = QCoreApplication::applicationName();
QString exePath = QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath();

// Define the embedded PowerShell scripts as strings
const QString checkFirewallScript = QString(
"param([string]$ruleName,[string]$exePath)"
"a powershell script of 70 lines"
).arg(ruleName, exePath);

// Construct the PowerShell command with the script
QString command = QString("powershell.exe -Command \"%1\"").arg(checkFirewallScript);

// Convert the command to a wide string
LPCWSTR commandC = (const wchar_t*) command.utf16();

// Use ShellExecute to run the command as administrator
HINSTANCE exitCode = ShellExecute(NULL, L"runas", L"powershell.exe", commandC, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

My exit code is always 42 though I read where above 32, it is just the instance number. I get a warning within the Qt error box of "QString::arg: 2 argument(s) missing in" and it spits out the script. I have no percent signs and the script works in powershell by itself (when I add the 2 "missing" arguments directly to script). This also worked without issue when I was using Qt Process, but I want UAC to be invoked so I am using ShellExecute (which is ShellExecuteW according to headers).

command repeats the executable name. That's not correct. For proper error reporting call ShellExecuteExW instead. Neither API call (nor CreateProcessW for that matter) will report the outcome of the newly created process.

The proper way when using Qt ist the QProcess API. You should remove the Qt tags from your question or reformulate with QProcess.

@Jens You're right. I'm trying to have UAC brought up so I'm not really using Qt, other than some initial strings.

// Get the application file path and name
QString ruleName = QCoreApplication::applicationName();
QString exePath = QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath();

// Define the embedded PowerShell scripts as strings
const QString checkFirewallScript = R"(param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ruleName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$exePath
    )
    $rules = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $ruleName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    ...
)";

// Construct the command to run PowerShell with the script
QString command = QString("-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -F \"%1\" -ruleName \"%2\" -exePath \"%3\"")
                      .arg(tempScriptPath)
                      .arg(ruleName)
                      .arg(exePath);

// Convert the command to a wide string
std::wstring commandW = command.toStdWString();

// Initialize the SHELLEXECUTEINFO structure
SHELLEXECUTEINFOW sei = {0};
sei.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOW);
sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOASYNC | SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
sei.hwnd = NULL;
sei.lpVerb = L"runas";
sei.lpFile = L"powershell.exe";
sei.lpParameters = commandW.c_str();;
sei.lpDirectory = NULL;
sei.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
sei.hInstApp = NULL;

//run
if (!ShellExecuteExW(&sei)) { ...

WaitForSingleObject(sei.hProcess, 10000);    // 10 seconds
DWORD exitCode;
GetExitCodeProcess(sei.hProcess, &exitCode);
CloseHandle(sei.hProcess);

if (exitCode == 18000) {

It took a bit of doing, had to forgo running the entire script as an argument because I kept encountering too many issues. This lets me run powershell in its own window while also requesting admin permissions to do some firewall maintenance. Thanks to
IInspectable for reccomending ShellExecuteExW, I can do custom error codes in the script. I didn't post the entire script + function, but this represents the good parts.

had to wait 2 days
